# php mysql Connect Database from another server

Tags: php, mysql, database

Connect Database from another server in mysql and php
 I use this :

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("mysite.com", "theusername", "proud");
mysql_select_db("theotherserverDB",$db);

?>
```

need to Fix?

Comment: Well, do you?  Do you get any errors?  What makes you think that there is a problem?

Comment: This is where I say RTFM: [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: Hassan- have you connected from other server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php

mysql_connect("mysite.com:3306", "admin", "1admin") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";

?>
```

Just run it and see if it works.

Comment: its not work... i want to connect database from different server

Comment: All you need to do is use the servers ip address or direct domain name, you may or may not need to use the port, the default is 3306, but it should make the connection. What error is the output.

Comment: I have same problem, ERROR IS: `Access denied for user 'tradetip'@'gator1679.hostgator.com' (using password: YES) in /home/tradecom/public_html/index.php on line 367`

Comment: I am getting error "Connection timed out".

Answer (score 0):

Before making the connection.. you should reserve the domain or IP address of the server you are about to communicate from....

If you are using cpanel you can do this by clicking on remote MYSQL under databases.

Good luck...