# Access a MySql Database from PHP (not on localhost)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

there's this server:
http://phpmyadmin.pvdata.fr/index.php ,
I can connect to it knowing the username and password and Server Choice.

Once I connect to it, it shows under MySql the following information: (I'm Translating from French)

```
Server:  sql6 (sql6 via TCP/IP)
Server Version: 5.0.92-87
Protocol Version: 10
Username: pvdata@10.5.1.3
Character for MySql: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)
```

So I tried using the following code in order to connect to the Database:

```
<?php
// Create connection
$username = "pvdata";
$password = "xxxxxxxx";
$hostname = "10.5.1.3"; 
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
?>
```

But it didn't work, it's saying: "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time". 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm new here, don't give me a down vote, just tell me what I'm doing wrong please.

Comment: First off, mysql_* functions are deprecated. Resort to mysqli_functions or PDO. Second, looking at the error message you are getting, I would suggest double checking your hostname and checking Firewall access

Comment: `10.5.1.3` is a local IP. Unless your PHP code is also on the same LAN then you need to use the server's public IP on the internet.

Comment: My PHP code is on the same LAN actually, how do I know the server's public IP?

Comment: @MrCode checkout [public IP](http://whatismyipaddress.com/)

Comment: @6339 it gives me the ip of my LAN I guess which is: 85.171.54.125,
so what's the hostname knowing that ip?

Comment: @maggie Is the database and the machine running PHP and PhpMyAdmin all the same machine ? Then for hostname just use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: @nl-x   no it's on another server

Comment: @maggie Mysql is on another server? Your PHP script and phpMyAdmin are on the same machine ?

Comment: @nl-x I don't think phpMyAdmin is on the same machine, because to access it I have to go to http://phpmyadmin.pvdata.fr/ which has a different content than localhost/phpmyadmin

Comment: @maggie then it's quite hard to help you. You need to know what IP to use from the Php server running you script to access the Mysql server. Somehow the phpMyAdmin is already configured to that IP. Maybe you can take a look in the phpMyAdmin configuration to see what IP it uses to access MySQL

Comment: @nl-x I think the ip is 10.5.1.3 but maybe the problem is about including sql6 as a server choice, because by default it's sql1 and I don't how to do that

Comment: @nl-x or http://195.114.18.168/ is actually the ip

Comment: @maggie I think 10.5.1.3 is the IP address of the server running phpMyAdmin. Not the MySQL server

Comment: @maggie 195.114.18.168 is also the server running phpMyAdmin. And probably not the IP address to the mysql database

Comment: @maggie can you access the phpMyAdmin script files ? I will write you an answer below

Comment: @maggie by the way , what is the url to your script? or what does the url start with ?

Comment: what script ? u mean http://phpmyadmin.pvdata.fr/index.php?

Comment: @maggie did you tried `195.114.18.162` this ip? because this is what getting the [IP](http://whatismyipaddress.com/hostname-ip) of your host name..

Comment: @nl-x if you mean the code, it's on the localhost,
written in C:\wamp\www\access server

Comment: @6339 yes I tried, didn't work.
I think there's still the problem of saying I want sql6 instead of 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your phpMyAdmin installation and look for the file `config.inc.php`. Open that file, and check which hostname / ip is being used for SQL6. That is the IP you should use for your `mysql_connect()`

Comment: I don't think I have access from my machine to config.inc.php, it's not the one on the localhost

Answer (score 0):

You need to search, google helps a lot, also you need to connect to an ip/domain and port of your MySQL server.
For this, you need to know what is the port of your mysql server.

Look this answer from [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765711/php-mysql-connect-database-from-another-server)

```
<?php

mysql_connect("mysite.com:3306", "admin", "1admin") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";

?>
```

to check if you have coneccion, try in console:

> shell> mysql --host=remote.example.com --port=3306  //3306 is the
>   defaul port for MySQL

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html

Comment: This is not an answer. More of a comment maybe. And the port number is not mandatory.

Comment: I think the problem is with the hostname I'm using 10.5.1.3, but I don't know what I should use instead

Comment: check this tutorial, maybe is a problem of permision to acces [link]http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: it's for linux, I'm using windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a firewall issue. Most 3rd party hosts don't allow you to access MySQL from 'the outside'.

You can do this if you manage the MySQL server yourself or if you have a host that doesn't deny you to access the database from another machine, but in regular web hosting, this is not common.

Comment: I can access MySql once I enter the username, password and Sql Choice directly on  http://phpmyadmin.pvdata.fr/index.php.
The problem is I'm not being able to access it from PHP.
(note: The server is on the same LAN as the php code)